# Remembering search scopes using Sharepoint search

Tags: jquery, search, sharepoint-2010

On the master page of our Sharepoint site we have an out of the box SharePoint search box which uses the scopes feature.  When a user chooses a particular scope (for example ‘people’), and hits 'Search' the site goes to the relevant page but the scope reverts back to ‘All Sites’.

Is there any way (jQuery maybe?) that I can set the scope to be what the user had previously selected?  I have users telling me that they want to keep searching for people, and at the moment they keep having to remember to change the scope back as its reverts to ‘All Sites’ after each submission.

This is how the Search box looks on our page

```
<SPSWC:SearchBoxEx ID="SmallSearchBox" runat="server" ShowAdvancedSearch="false" 
       QueryPromptString="Search our site"  DropDownMode="DisplayScopeDD" 
       SearchResultPageURL="/pages/search.aspx"               
       ScopeDisplayGroupName="Search Dropdown" ShowQuerySuggestions="True" 
       TextBeforeDropDown="" FrameType="None"  DisplaySubmittedSearch="true" 
       SuppressWebPartChrome="true" SearchBoxTableClass="" />
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I believe this can be done by changing the DropDownMode of the web part on your *results* page to either **ShowDD_DefaultURL** or **ShowDD_NoContextual_DefaultURL**.

This will cause the search scope in the web part to default to the 's' URL parameter, which is specified in the submitted query string. For example, if you search using the 'People' scope, you will have "&s=People" appended to your query string, and the selected search scope on the results page will also be 'People'.

Further info on DropDownMode options can be found here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.portal.webcontrols.dropdownmodes.aspx, although unfortunately it doesn't go into much detail.